# Cropping large DEM data file and save as separate file using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

How do I crop a section of the US map I am working on from the larger DEM data and save as a separate file on ArcMap 10.2?

Answer (score 2):

Create a Polygon Boundary of your area of study then use the polygon as your clipping boundary in the [Raster Processing Clip Tool](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/data_management_tools/clip_data_management_.htm).

In ArcToolbox:
Select

```
Data Management Tools>Raster>Raster Processing>Clip
```

[image]

populate the Clip Tool with your desired settings. 
[image]

BE SURE TO ADD YOUR EXTENSION in the Output Raster Dataset field
[image]

[GIS Geography](http://gisgeography.com/) provides a good article on [How to Clip Rasters to Polygon Boundaries in ArcGIS](http://gisgeography.com/clip-rasters-arcgis-polygon-boundary/)

Answer (score 1):

I find that simple is best...
Using the drawing tool draw a graphic box around the area you want to clip.
Right mouse on Image and select "Data" then "Export Data"
Pick you image type and select OK.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Clip tool for this. There are several ways, the least RAM intensive way for a large file:

1. In the image analysis window, use the clip area tool for a general space around the region of interest you have. This will create a temporary layer file.
2. Create a new polygon for the study area you're looking at, which will be a polygon shapefile. Do this within the arc catalog window within Arcmap [right click on an empty folder/geodatabase; select 'create shapefile]
3. Open the edit feature toolbar, and select your newly created shapefile to be edited, draw a polygon and save the edit: this is your new study area
4. run the 'clip' tool, with the new study area as the polygon to clip your temporary image layer to ---> this will be your final DEM image clipped to the area you need.